# Cannot access the files inside public folder in Laravel 8

Tags: php, leaflet, laravel-8

I'm kind of a beginner in laravel. I've been trying to put an image as an icon in leaflet.js map and using laravel 8 as a backend. I have put my image in "public/images/image_name.png" and access it using the following code from the blade template.

```
var leafletIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: "{{ asset('images/test_image.png') }}",
    iconSize: [38, 38],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
});
```

Please note that I am writing the above lines of code inside the script tag of the blade template and not the html part. The problem is that I can't access the public folder of the laravel project by any means. The icon does not show up in the map.

What I have done -

- I tried to access it via the url from chrome with http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/test_image.png and it gives me "ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE".
- I have double checked the filenames and paths.
- To test further, I also created a css folder directly under public folder and created a style.css, put some styles and tried to call it from the blade templates as well as from the url bar but similar issue persist and styles are not applied. It seemed to me that access to public folder is somehow restricted.
- I also tried url() instead of asset() but with no luck.
- I called the public_path() function to check my public directory and it shows "mylocalfilesystem/my_project_name/public" which is correct as far as I know.
  As a note, I'm running laravel 8 with php artisan serve on my local machine

This is my .htaccess file inside the public folder

```
IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Please help me resolve this issue, thank you.

Comment: From the app folder, can you try `php -S localhost:8000 -t public/` ?

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier By app folder, do you mean the project root directory?

Comment: Yes, the project root directory

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved the issue. I can now see the icon. But I wonder what's the problem with php artisan serve though. @ClémentBaconnier

Comment: Similar issue with the php artisan serve, yes.